# jQuery UI Accordion - animation does not work

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

Thanks for your help in advance.

I am using the jQuery UI accordion and I would like there to be an animation but for some reason it does not work. Any idea why? the accordion div simply appears and disappears. Here is my code:

```
      <!-- creates  accordion where records can be entered -->
                    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $( "#tracking-record-menu" ).accordion({
                collapsible: true,
                    header: '.record-item',
                active: false,
                animated: 'slide'
            });

                            });

                    </script>    

          <!--######### contains tracking record buttons ######## -->
               <div id="tracking-record-container"> 
          <ul id="tracking-record-menu">

<li class="record-section"><span class="record-section-text">Body Metrics</span></li>

<li class="record-item"><div class="record-item-div"><span class="record-text">Distance</span></div></li>

                     <div class="tooltip-record">
                     <form id="distance_graphtracker" method="post" action="">
                     <label for="distance-log-id">Distance</label>
         <input type="text" name="distance_log" id="distance-log-id" />
                     <button type="submit" name="submit_distance" >Record</button>
                     </form>
                     </div>

<li class="record-item"><div class="record-item-div"><span class="record-text">Time</span></div></li>

                     <div class="tooltip-record">
                     <form id="time_graphtracker" method="post" action="">
                     <label for="time-log-id">Time</label>
          <input type="text" name="time_log" id="time-log-id" />
                     <button type="submit" name="submit_time" >Record</button>
                     </form>
                     </div>

</ul>
</div>
```

P.S. I have included the UI Effects Core.

Comment: make a demo that reproduce the problem you face at http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

Your animation can be broken if you use css like:

```
.accordion_item_content { height: auto !important; }
```

Because in that case that element cannot be animated (you override all changes). In that case you should use option autoHeight: true in accordion.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle using your code but the slide effect looks like it is firing correctly:
http://jsfiddle.net/Xzjum/

Can you include your CSS, maybe there is something effecting the slide animation?

Comment: Thank you Lokase for the help. Unfortunately I am at work and won't have access to my home computer for a few more  hours, but  what kind of css properties could be preventing the animation? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Not sure, but without seeing the entire picture (i.e. - your CSS styling) we can't really determine where the problem is.